# Return in which or statement results are from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join, union

I'm having the following SQL statement, to return worksheets that teachers have liked, and worksheets that teachers made by themselves.

```
SELECT worksheets.title, worksheets.worksheet_id
FROM worksheets
WHERE worksheets.worksheet_id 
IN (
    SELECT worksheet_id FROM likes WHERE teacher_id = 5
) OR worksheets.worksheet_id 
IN (
    SELECT worksheet_id FROM worksheets WHERE teacher_id = 5
)
```

It's working fine, but now I also want to return if the worksheet was liked, or made by the teacher. How do I do that? I tried things with an if statement, but could not figure out a working solution.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: oracle, postgres, mysql...?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a `left join` and conditional logic?

```
select w.title, w.worksheet_id,
    (w.teacher_id = 5)           as is_made,
    (l.worksheet_id is not null) as is_liked
from worksheets w
left join from likes l 
    on l.worksheet_id = w.worksheet_id and l.teacher_id = 5
where w.teacher_id = 5 or l.worksheet_id is not null
```

This puts the "made or like" information in two different columns (after all, a teacher could have made *and* liked a worksheek).

`OR` sometimes kills performance. `union all` might be more efficient:

```
select title, worksheet_id, max(is_made) as is_made, max(is_liked) as is_liked
from (
    select title, worksheet_id, 1 as is_made, 0 as is_liked 
    from worksheets 
    where teacher_id = 5
    union all
    select w.title, w.worksheet_id, 0, 1
    from worksheets w
    where exists (select 1 from likes l where j.teacher_id = 5 and l.worksheet_id = w.worksheet_id)
) t
group by title, worksheet_id
```

Comment: Thanks, the last one worked for me. Only after I had to change t.teacher_id into l.teacher_id.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a slight change keeping `IN` operator such as

```
SELECT title, worksheet_id
  FROM worksheets
 WHERE worksheet_id IN (
      SELECT worksheet_id FROM likes WHERE teacher_id = 5
     )
   OR teacher_id = 5
```

or you can use an outer `JOIN`

```
SELECT title, w.worksheet_id
  FROM worksheets w
  LEFT JOIN likes l
    ON l.worksheet_id = w.worksheet_id
 WHERE 5 IN (w.teacher_id ,l.teacher_id)
```

as an alternative

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0c8b721276b30036e6ebb77f221f3e2a)</kbd>

but I didn't understand what you meant by *the worksheet was liked, or made by the teacher* even if they seem to need conditionals along with some column, but how? The logic is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title, worksheet_id, IF(likes.worksheet_id IS NOT NULL, 'Likes', 'Worksheet') AS source 
FROM worksheets 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT worksheet_id FROM likes WHERE teacher_id = 5) AS likes ON worksheets.worksheet_id = likes.worksheet_id
WHERE worksheet_id 
IN (
    SELECT worksheet_id FROM likes WHERE teacher_id = 5
) OR worksheets.teacher_id = 5
```

Try This, hope it helps